# Win32 обновление окна в фоне

Tags: c++, winapi

Есть Win32 приложение: окно и единственный TextBox. В цикле `while(GetMessage(...` проверяется некоторое событие. Если оно установлено, то в `TextBox`-е обновляется текст (берется из Mapped области, но это, думаю, неважно).

Проблема такая: если окно в фоне, то обновления не происходит. Как только щелкаю по окошку, то все нормально обновляется. Вопрос: можно ли сделать так, чтобы это происходило всегда, даже в фоне.

Пробовал в конце цикла `while(GetMessage(...` (уже после `TranslateMessage` и `DispatchMessage`) отправить себе `WM_USER`, но не помогло.

Comment: Обычный `UpdateWindow`  пробовали?

Comment: Не помогает. Но текст обновляется не при активации окна, а даже если по textBox-у (напомню, окно в фоне) провести курсором мыши

Comment: так по условию обновлять в отдельном потоке, например проверяем, если окно не активно, то обновляем: `if (GetForegroundWindow() != ваш_hwnd)UpdateWindow(ваш_HWND)`

Comment: Хм, думал про что-нибудь такое, но казалось, что это из разряда "Из пушки по воробьям". Похоже, ошибался( Спасибо, попробую.

Comment: Я исходил из ваших целей), возможно есть еще варианты решения проблемы))), но это то, что пришло мне в голову с самого начала.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как я не совсем понял суть вопроса, поэтому предложу 3 разных варианта.

Все это дело придется вынести в отдельный поток, потому что обработчик событий окна не будет ловить события "бездействия"(события когда окно не активно)!

Если тормознуть цикл в потоке, в котором будет выполнятся вся эта магия `Sleep(1);` - то будет вполне экономно для ваших нужд.

Для обновления `textBox`, нужно передать его HWND!

Вариант 1:

```
if (GetForegroundWindow() != ваш_hwnd)UpdateWindow(ваш_HWND)
```

Вариант 2:

```
//Использовать MoveWindow, с флагом true
MoveWindow(hwnd, (int)position.x, (int)position.y, (int)position.w, (int)position.h, true);
//Получить тукущую позицию окна:
RECT WindowRect{};
GetWindowRect(hwnd, &WindowRect)
```

Вариант 3:

```
RedrawWindow//с нужными вам флагами
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, я попробую. Но остается вопрос: почему НЕактивное окно все же обновлялось, если курсором через него "проехаться"?

Comment: @Алексей Саровский, это обычное событие обработчика окна, срабатывает при фильтре событий с флагом `WM_MOUSEMOVE`, если я не ошибаюсь, можете проверить так: `LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {

switch (message) {
case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
     printf_s("Событие!\n");break;
default: 
     return 0;
}
return 0;
}`